# instrumentation/unit testing for different build variants

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to include an instrumentation test directory for each different build variants.

Currently I have 3 different build variants:

```
alpha {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/integration-alpha/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/alpha/res', 'src/alphaProd/res']
      }
beta {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/beta/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/beta/java', 'src/beta/java']
     }
gamma {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/gamma-integration/java', 'src/gamma/java']
     }
```

How can I set my Gradle so that I will have an "androidTest" or an instrumentation test for each of these build variants.

*I'm trying to avoid having **ONE** unit test for all of the build variants because they have some different functionality.*